# Almost new GCFI tripping, while breaker not tripping

Tags: electrical, wiring

I just re-wired my house and put most of the lights onto one circuit. It’s a 15 amp circuit and I ran everything to a GCFI first so that I could shut off the lights with the push of a button. Recently the GCFI has been tripping immediately after I push the button in.

I disconnected the GCFI, and used wire nuts to connect the wires Then flipped the breaker and the lights are staying on. This GCFI is pretty new, within a couple months or so. I know they typically go bad and do this but seems pretty soon for that to be happening. Is it possible that there’s some type of backfeed in my circuit, that’s causing it to flip, that my GCFI is catching, but not my breaker?

It just throws me off because it has been working fine for the past two months and I’ve done nothing to the circuit. My furnace is off and the apartment was probably at 35-40 degrees over the night. Could that have something to do with it?

Comment: "I ran everything to a GCFI first so that I could shut off the lights with the push of a button" ...  So you're using the GFCI outlet as a switch??

Comment: @crip659 many gfci are actually designed to be used as switches

Comment: @manassehkatz,  I haven't encountered the GFCIs that can be used as switches. They could be very helpful to me.  I googled GFCI switches, but just came up with the normal GFCI's.  Can you direct me to what you are referring to please?

Comment: Found one.  But it is unclear if the switch will open the circuit through the GFCI or after the CGFI, or if the switch is just a switch in one unit with a gfci.

Comment: Installing a GFCI (outlet, one presumes) to use as a light switch seems like there's an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) hiding in there somewhere. _WHY_ are you using the GFCI test/reset buttons as a light switch? Especially since it's "most of the lights" in the whole house.

Comment: Push-button switches are made, albeit somewhat unusual these days, if turning lights on or off with "the literal push of a button" is important to you as opposed to using a toggle or paddle switch.

Answer (score 2):

GFCI outlets are meant to trip with an imbalance of current flow between hot and neutral, not because of an overload. Your breaker takes care of an overload.

From your question, it appears you're using the GFCI as a switch. If it's been working for a few months and you're constantly tripping and resetting it, you probably wore it out. The latching devices in the GFCIs are sensitive and not meant for continuous use.

Comment: Plus the obvious, "if you want a switch, install a switch".

Answer (score 2):

##### TL;DR If it looks like a ground fault, it probably *is* a ground fault!

But first:

- For those who say "why use a GFCI when you should use a switch", there **are** switch-rated GFCIs, such as [this Leviton from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-20-Amp-125-Volt-Combo-Self-Test-Blank-Face-GFCI-Outlet-White-R98-GFRBF-0KW/206001151):

[image: Leviton GFCI]

If it has ON and OFF next to RESET and TEST, then it is OK to use it as an occasional switch. That being said, there are also GFCI/switch combinations, such as [this Leviton from Home Depot](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Leviton-15-Amp-125-Volt-Combo-Self-Test-Tamper-Resistant-GFCI-Outlet-and-Switch-White-R92-GFSW1-0KW/206000203):

[image: Leviton GFCI Switch]

which are arguably better for frequent switching as the switch part is an ordinary switch and doesn't actually trip the GFCI circuit to turn itself off.

In addition, hardwired lighting generally does *not* require GFCI protection except over a tub or shower or next to a pool, etc. That is because GFCI is about human safety (as opposed to AFCI about fire prevention) and if you can't touch the light easily (it is in the ceiling) the risk from a ground fault is extremely low. So why even use a GFCI here?

All that being said:

- You likely have an **actual ground fault**. That is what causes GFCIs to trip. Their raison dêtre. One possibility is that the low temperatures cause condensation and the condensation gets into a poorly sealed connection and causes the GFCI to trip.

Comment: In the question and answers for your first picture, it states the unit isn't meant for continuous switching.  " Hi , Thank you for choosing Leviton. No, that device is intended to provide GFCI protection to the circuit but not as an everyday switch. However you may be able to use our GFSW1-W."

From a Leviton rep.
Apr 4, 2021

Comment: I think the ON, OFF notation is to clarify what the RESET, TEST buttons do.

Comment: I have my lighting on a GFCI-protected circuit (with nothing else on it.) Had a major condensation problem which tripped the GFCI (and not the breaker) due to water collecting in the lights. I solved the condensation problem and haven't had a trip since. (I don't use the GFCI as a switch for my lights - I have light switches for that purpose, after the GFCI.)

Comment: @JACK I disagree. Most leviton gfci don't have on off marked.